# ChromeDriver version mismatch error: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 91

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I have found out that my `current chrome version is 96.0.4664.45`

Now, when I install the correct ChromeDriver version from [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=96.0.4664.45/) and run, it still throws this error-

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 91
Current browser version is 96.0.4664.45 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

Can someone please help me sort this out?

Comment: You probably want to use `chromedriver-binary`, using `pip` to install the appropriate version: https://pypi.org/project/chromedriver-binary/

Answer (score 1):

It seems a problem with system executable path. Try linking your chromedriver.exe with correct path with adjusting your old path;

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"NEW_VERSION_PATH\chromedriver.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

Please download chrome driver from [here](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/).

Once downloaded please place it in the current project directory, or any directory which is not sensitive from the Windows OS perspective.

and then use it like this

```
driver_path = r'C:\\Users\\userid\\some_folder\\Desktop\\Automation\\chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 91
Current browser version is 96.0.4664.45 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chrome=96.0.4664.45*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v96.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/96.0.4664.45/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports Chrome version 96

- But you are using *chromedriver=91.0*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=91.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/91.0.4472.101/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports Chrome version 91

So there is a clear mismatch between *chromedriver=91.0* and the *chrome=96.0.4664.45*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v96.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=96.0.4664.45/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *chrome=96.0.4664.45* (as per [chrome=96.0.4664.45 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/96.0.4664.45/notes.txt)).